# ASP.NET MVC View for Object with Embedded Objects

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am struggling to figure out how to approach creating a view for an object that creates other objects.

Here is a simplified example of what I am trying to accomplish:

```
public class Classroom
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int RoomNumber { get; set; }

    public string SchoolID { get; set; }
    public School School { get; set; }
}

public class School
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

So when accessing the view used to create a new classroom, I want the user to be able to enter a school name.  Then, when the form is submitted, I want it to attempt to resolve the school name to an existing school.  If it finds a school with the specified name, it will use that school when creating the classroom object.  Otherwise, it will create a new school and add that to the classroom object.

What is the best way to approach this?

p.s. I am using the latest Entity Framework with Visual Studio 2013

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by: creating a view for an object that creates other objects.

Comment: possible duplicate of [View for Object with Nested Classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21326586/view-for-object-with-nested-classes)

Comment: Please say why this question is different from your earlier question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21326586/view-for-object-with-nested-classes

Comment: It's not actually - I think that this is a better stated version (I wasn't getting any responses at the time for my other one) -

Comment: How can you add a new school only based on a name? What if the name is misspelled? And is a school nothing but a name? (I realize this may be a contrived example, but I can't think of any real-life scenario where this would a good pattern). Anyway, technically you could use the AddOrUpdate method (DbSet).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a ViewModel.

```
public class CreateClassroomModel
{
    public string SchoolName { get; set; }
    public int RoomNumber { get; set; } 
}

public async Task<ActionResult> PostClassroom(CreateClassroomModel model)
{
    var school = await _db.Schools
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Name == model.SchoolName)
        ?? new School { Name = model.SchoolName };
    var classroom = new Classroom
    {
        RoomNumber = model.RoomNumber,
        School = school,
    };
    _db.Classrooms.Add(classroom);
    await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
    return RedirectToAction("CreateClassroomSuccess");
}
```

... then your view would just have textboxes for school name and classroom room number. When you post the form, the action above does what you want. If it finds a school with a matching name, that school is used. Otherwise, it creates a new school. Either way, it will always create a new classroom.

If you don't want to use the EF6 async features, here's how to do it without async:

```
public ActionResult PostClassroom(CreateClassroomModel model)
{
    var school = _db.Schools.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == model.SchoolName)
        ?? new School { Name = model.SchoolName };
    var classroom = new Classroom
    {
        RoomNumber = model.RoomNumber,
        School = school,
    };
    _db.Classrooms.Add(classroom);
    _db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("CreateClassroomSuccess");
}
```

Comment: Curious, what is the need for the async implementation?

Comment: @AaronPalmer no need, it's just there because the OP said he was using the latest EF. Maybe I should write a non-async version of the answer?

Comment: Async does generate more IL than sync code.  Using async is typically an architectural decision that should be made during initial design, because it will drive many design decisions.  Not saying async isn't interesting or helpful, it is, but may not be the best fit given the system.

Comment: @AaronPalmer, I've updated with a non-async version of the code.

Comment: perfect - I really appreciate both the sync and async versions - I'm going to use sync for this but I actually do need async for something very similar - thank you!

Comment: so then do I not explicitly set the SchoolID before saving it to the _db?  Assuming EF does this automatically - when is it done?

Comment: You can set either SchoolId or the School navigation property. After SaveChanges, the other will become populated. You can also set both if you like, but you only need to set one of them, unless some part of your code needs to access both properties before saving changes.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you will have list of schools from DbContext, so when you get name of the school in your controller's action you can do this.  Assume that your action in controller has schoolName parameter

```
using (var context = new MyDBContext())
{
    var school = context.Schools().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == schoolName);

    if (school == null)
    {
        // create new school
    }
    else
    {
        var classroom = new Classroom
        {
            School = school,
            // set other properties
        }
    }
}
```